# kotlin-room figure out how to save this field

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I upload information to the Book class.

```
tableName = "Books_name"  data class Books(  // @Embedded  // val additional_imgs: MutableList<String>,  val adult: Int,  val author: String,  val bookmark: Int,  val chapters: MutableList<Chapter>? = null,  val chapters_total: Int,  // @Embedded  // val comments: MutableList<Comment>,  autoGenerate = true  val id: Int? = null,  val img: String,  val lang: String,  val last_activity: Int,  val n_chapters: Int,  val publisher: String,  val rating: String,  val s_title: String,  val status: String,  val t_title: String,  // val team: Int,  val writer: String,  val year: String  )
```

Book has a class Chapter

```
//@Entity(tableName = "Books_name") 
data class Chapter( 
val can_read: Boolean, 
// autoGenerate = true 
val id_glavs_list: Int, 
val new: Boolean, 
val status: String, 
val title: String 
)
```

But after adding this class, an error appears. I was looking for information, but everywhere they say that this is corrected by cleaning the project. But it does not help. EROR:

> Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have
>   an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the
>   fields (by name and type). - java.util.List

Comment: i guess the problem comes with the list, cause its an interface and has therefore no constructor

Comment: @IEE1394 what needs to be fixed?

Comment: sorry i dont know andriod-room .. but maybe try some specific list e.g. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/index.html

Comment: Can you clean up your code?

Comment: @musooff I do not understand

Comment: @ЕгорГлухов can you remove unrelated code lines. Like, you have so many comment outs `//`. Your `Book` class doesn't have closing brackets, doesn't have `@Entity` annotation.